# How to use DevExpress GridView with no callback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have this code in my controller controller:

```
List<TResult> list = db.GetBigData();
return PartialView("GridViewPartialView", list);
```

View:

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "gvGrouping";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Display", Action = "GridViewPartialView" };
        settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSort = false;
        settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
        settings.SettingsPager.Visible = false;

//create many column
        settings.Settings.ShowGroupPanel = true;

        };
    }).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

On the first run, the controller executes the `GetBigData` method. The view shows, but all the nodes are collapsed.  If I click a node, it will callback to the controller which again will create a new query to the database. The same thing happens with sorting.  I do not want there to be a request to the database every time, so how can I avoid the callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GridView is a server side control which performs all data calculations on the server and sends only a tiny portion to the client. Since the client side doesn't have all data available, it cannot re-sort or re-group it when necessary. It sends a callback to the server instead.

All you can do is to speed up callback. First thing you should do is enable server-mode which will greatly reduce amount of data transfered from the database. Here is how you can enable it: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3726